# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Windows

Tags: java, windows

So I usually run my programs through Eclipse but I'm not allowed to use it in an upcoming competition, so I started trying to compile my programs through command prompt, and I kept getting the same error for everything I tried to compile... I have searched for answers but none of them seemed to be my problem. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you and sorry if there is already an answer to this.

```
C:\Users\DanielH\Desktop\Folder>javac Test.java

C:\Users\DanielH\Desktop\Folder>java Test.class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Test.class.  Program will exit.
```

Test.java was written as:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; 

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        Scanner fish=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=fish.nextInt();
        int b=a-10;
        System.out.println(b);
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `java Test`.  The `.` (dot) is a package separator, so the JVM is trying to find the class named `class` in the folder `Test` (see `NoClassDefFoundError: Test/class`)

Comment: ..and remember to read the documentation about compiling and executing a Java application: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your code in Package structure and try to run from package after compiling it.